# add link in @UniqueEntity message

Tags: symfony, orm

hi i am using symfony 5.4, and trying to add html code to uniqueentity message:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user",columns={"id","credential","nickname","email","status"})})
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"},
 *     message="este Correo ya esta en Uso; Dirigete a la Activacion de Cuentas! <a href='/account_activation'>Activate</a>"
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
```

in this case I want a link to be shown in the error but I don't get it:

[image]

this is the twig template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {# display any flash message #}
    {% for label, messages in app.flashes %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ label }} alert-dismissible fade show">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form(registration_form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

any idea how i can achieve it?

**update**

i try to add raw error filter:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ error.message|raw }}
    {% for label, messages in app.flashes %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ label }} alert-dismissible fade show">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form(registration_form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

but get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two weeks of research:

Use the message property that uses uniqueentity in annotation, it is not the correct way (is a bad practice) if you want to implement any element/structure html.

**all properties are encoded to avoid xss attacks**, there are 2 ways to follow using the controller:

1. forget about the html tag and use a direct redirect to the desired path instead of a link:

```php
if (count($form['email']->getErrors(true)) > 0) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('account_activation');
}
```

2. implement a custom error handler and display the error concatenated to the html tag:

```php
if (count($form['email']->getErrors(true)) > 0) {
    $this->addFlash(
        'warning',
        'your account need to be activated! <a href="account_activation">Click Here!</a>'
    );
}
```

**Note:** implementing the second option requires adding the [Flash Messages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages) output to the form template.

There is another unverified method that the github site gave me but I could not verify its functionality:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/44755#issuecomment-999156755

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme registration_form _self %}
{% block form_errors %}
    {%- for error in errors -%}
        {{ error.message | raw }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_errors(registration_form) }}
    {{ form(registration_form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you display it on the front? If you use Twig, maybe you forgot to use [raw](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html) filter?

```
   {{ error.message|raw }}
```

Comment: hello i have not adde any error output, in tampleate for error i think that flash is showqing or symfony show it near the input. i have update the question with the twig template content.

Comment: Try:
{{ form_errors(registration_form.email)|raw }}

Comment: ok i have add it to the uppfer of flash ... and i get it twice ... and link (anchor) is not working: https://i.imgur.com/yoo0k8e.png

Comment: i have public it on github https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/44755

Comment: after some test you workaround not work ...